# sublime text 3 on mac os not keeping project open

Tags: macos, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm using sublime text 3 on mac. Whenever I've had a project or folder open and closed the window (not quit the app) it would remember where i last left off, and open my last window. I noticed now when I close the window it gives me a blank document. I have to go browse to open the project. Is there some setting I'm missing?

EDIT:  okay I guess this is because the application hasnt really exited when i hit the red x.. its still running but i just closed my tabs.  is there any way to make sublime text quit when all its windows are closed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To maintain project settings in Sublime, you need to quit the entire application instead of just closing the windows. Use <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> to quit, or select **`Sublime Text -> Quit`**. There is no way to make the program quit when just closing the windows, OS X generally doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 2):

You should use RedQuits, quits app when closing last window http://www.carsten-mielke.com/redquits.html